# BatchRequest() is a single transaction or many?

Tags: web3js

`web3.BatchRequest();`
does it produce a single transaction with several functions of the (possibly different) contracts or not?

```
  var batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
  batch.add(web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction.request(raw3, (err,tx3Hash) =>{
  console.log('err:', err, 'tx3Hash:', tx3Hash)  
  }))
  batch.add(web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction.request(raw4, (err,tx4Hash) =>{
  console.log('err:', err, 'tx4Hash:', tx4Hash)  
  }))
  batch.execute()
```

this code gives me two different transactions, how i can have them in one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BatchRequest batches only JSON-RPC calls for your Ethereum node API. Transactions are independent and separate concern of those. BatchRequest only saves you some modest amount of HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thanks! I have only 15 rep and cant upvote your answer.

Comment: Can BatchRequest save gas fee? thanks.

Comment: BatchRequest does not save gas.