# how to sign a batch of transaction with a private key in web3.js

Tags: web3js, dapps, typescript

I have created a batch of transactions with the help of web3.js.

1. Firstly I am batching transactions with the "approve" method of the erc20 contract to approve a smart contract of the tokens present in the wallet
2. Then I batch a custom method of "redeem".
3. I want to sign all these transactions or(batch of transactions) with a private key.They work fine if my metamask account is connected to the dapp i need to sign it from the frontend(with my private key) without the metamask popup by using my private key i.e web3.js
4. ```
     const batch = new web3.BatchRequest()
     batch.add(
           tokenContractWeb3.methods.approve(contract2.address, 
           Number(bal).toString()).send({
             from: grantorAddress,
           }),
         )
     batch.add(
       anotherContractWeb3.methods.redeem(1, '0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65').send({
         from: grantorAddress,
         }),
       )
     batch.execute()
   ```

Comment: i am trying to fetch the batch.requests.data but i am facing a error ```Property 'requests' does not exist on type 'BatchRequest'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BatchRequest() is a single transaction or many?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92767/batchrequest-is-a-single-transaction-or-many)

Comment: Didn’t help much

Comment: @SukiratWarring You should initialize web3.js with a wallet provider like [`@truffle/hdwallet-provider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) for signing the transactions.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I would comment but I just created this account to ask if you managed to solve this?

Comment: Nah man changed my approach...as far as i know i cannot be done...account abstractions solves this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. Batching in web3.js refers to only the batching of JSON-RPC calls. That means you can batch readonly calls (i.e. `balanceOf`, calls getting current prices on DEXs, etc.), but not transactions that are changing the state

You will need to sign and send the transactions to the network individually.

Comment: IS IT? because i was able to batch the approve and redeem method which are not readonly calls...but i want to sign these batch of transaction with my private key in the frontend and not from the metamask popup

Comment: Yes it is. You clearly weren't able to batch them as you receive an error, the error being that there are no requests in the BatchRequest. `.send` returns a 32 byte transaction hash, whereas the docs shows requests being generated using the `.request` method, therefore you never added any requests

Comment: I was able to batch them and sign them with my metamask pop-up and the transactions were successful ….my question is i want to sign these batched transactions with my private key present in the frontend